# I am creating a login panel, but no matter the combination of user & pass the login won't be accepted

Tags: java, authentication, panel

```
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
if (e.getSource() == btnCancel) {
    System.exit(0);
}
if (e.getSource() == btnLogin) {
    int i = 0;
    while (loggedIn == false) {
        if (i < TeacherData.length) {
        if (txtUsername.getText() == TeacherData[i].getUsername() && String.valueOf(txtPassword.getPassword()) == TeacherData[i].getPassword()) {
                loggedIn = true;
                System.out.println("Login Successful");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Invalid Username or Password.");
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

My login panel is coded to look like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHoiP.jpg.

Upon pressing the "login", the button the console prints out "Invalid Username or Password." 10 times (there are 10 teachers in teacherData).

Before anybody asks I have already made sure the `getUsername()` and `getPassword()` methods work. `txtUsername` is the name of the `JTextField` and `txtPassword` is the name of the `JPasswordField`. I do not receive any errors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

change this line:

```
if (txtUsername.getText() == TeacherData[i].getUsername() && String.valueOf(txtPassword.getPassword()) == TeacherData[i].getPassword()) {
```

to this

```
String password = String.valueOf(txtPassword.getPassword());
if (txtUsername.getText().equals(TeacherData[i].getUsername()) && password.equals(TeacherData[i].getPassword())){
```

with `==` you compare the object references and not the values.

As result of this you will never login successfully.

btw. the `String.valueOf` is not necessary.

`getPassword` returns a `char[]` `array`.
You have to convert it to String with: `String.valueOf(txtPassword.getPassword())`

Comment: I did as you instructed and replaced the line in my code but the same problem persists. the console prints out "Invalid Username or Password" 10 times as opposed to printing out "Login Successful" 1 time.

Comment: @Andres123: what is txtPassword for a class?

Comment: txtPassword is a JPasswordField

Comment: @Andres123: see my updated answer. getPassword returns char[] and not String. First of all it must be converted.

Comment: Yes that is what the String.valueOf was for, i fixed my issue, i had used the String.valueOf on the String as opposed to the char value from the jpasswordfield. it was simply misplaced thanks for the assistance.